# Merge two lists but choose one with higher property value c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of object

```
public class Items  
{
    public string Country;
    public string State;
    public string City;
    public DateTime date;
    public int population;
}
```

...

```
var items1 = new List<Items>
{
    new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",date="7/8/2016",population=1000},
    new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",date="10/8/2016",population=2000},
    new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",date="12/8/2016",population=3000},
    new Item {Country="Canada", State="Ontario",City="Washington",date="10/8/2016",population=3000},
};


var items2 = new List<Items>
{
   new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",date="10/8/2016",population=2500},
    new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",date="12/8/2016",population=2400},
    new Item {Country="Canada", State="Ontario",City="Washington",date="10/8/2016",population=3500},
};
```

I want to combine these two lists matching them on country, state City and date but choosing higher of two populations.

```
items1.Concat(items2) ...linq or lambda
```

resulting in

```
 {
    new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",date="7/8/2016",population=1000},
    new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",date="10/8/2016",population=2500},
    new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",date="12/8/2016",population=3000},
    new Item {Country="Canada", State="Ontario",City="Washington",date="10/8/2016",population=3500},
};
```

Comment: Your code doesn't appear it will compile. Which begs the question, have you tried to solve it yet? What was your approach (code) and which parts are you struggling with specifically?

Comment: its not a compilable code..just for stating my problem..two list..combine them and group them based on certain properties and choosing items based on higher population.

Comment: In the future, show us that you've attempted to solve the problem. It goes a long way.

Comment: Thanks for your help , I already solved it and its pretty similar to your approach.I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupBy is probably the trickiest part to solving this. Once you're past that, various approaches to getting the one you want in each grouping can work. Here's one.

We start by making an anonymous grouping on the four fields. Then we enumerate each group, order it's values descending by population, and select the first result.

```
var merged = new List<Item>(items1);
merged.AddRange(items2);

IEnumerable<Item> grouped = merged
    .GroupBy((item) => new { item.Country, item.State, item.City, item.date })
    .Select((item) => item.OrderByDescending(i => i.population).FirstOrDefault());

foreach(Item item in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Country}, {item.State}, {item.City}, {item.date}, {item.population}");
}
```

Result

```
USA, Washington, Seattle, 7/8/2016 12:00:00 AM, 1000
USA, Washington, Seattle, 10/8/2016 12:00:00 AM, 2500
USA, Washington, Seattle, 12/8/2016 12:00:00 AM, 3000
Canada, Ontario, Washington, 10/8/2016 12:00:00 AM, 3500
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the two lists and then group by `Country`, after that to order each group by `population` in descending order and get the first of the ordered elements:

```
        var items1 = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",population=1000},
            new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",population=2000},
            new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",population=3000},
            new Item {Country="Canada", State="Ontario",City="Washington",population=3000},
        };


        var items2 = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",population=1000},
            new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",population=2500},
            new Item {Country="USA", State="Washington",City="Seattle",population=2400},
            new Item {Country="Canada", State="Ontario",City="Washington",population=3500},
        };

        var items = items1.Concat(items2).GroupBy(i => i.Country).ToList();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Item itemWithHighestPopulation = item.OrderByDescending(i => i.population).FirstOrDefault();

            // Never concatenate strings with '+', I'm just using it for testing purposes
            Console.WriteLine(itemWithHighestPopulation.City + " " + itemWithHighestPopulation.Country + " " + itemWithHighestPopulation.population);
        }
```